# How to filter published content using view with REST

Tags: views

I'm using Drupal 8 and I've created a view with REST. I would like to filter my content, so I've created a field criteria and I've added a Published field and exposed.

When I use /my-view-path?status=1 show me published content,
when I use /my-view-path?status=0 show me unpublished content,
those are working good. But I would like to use /my-view-path?status=All and show me published and unpublished content.

This is how I've configured published field:

[image]

But I don't know how to do that, any help?

Comment: `/my-view-path` without any `?status` will show all. If you want `All`, use views arguments.

Comment: thank you @Nikit but i need to use that argument because i'm using another system to request that url

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding an 'All' option to a views exposed filter](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3590/adding-an-all-option-to-a-views-exposed-filter)