# How to add "all" option to exposed filter?

Tags: views, forms, 9

I see [this discussion](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3590/adding-an-all-option-to-a-views-exposed-filter) for Drupal 7 but am trying to do something similar in Drupal 9.

My view is called "content_display" and the display I am trying to affect is called ct_list (see screenshot). [image]

Currently an exposed form sorts by title(screenshot).[image]

The All option is defined in the view and going to path/all shows all just like path/a shows articles starting with the letter a.

Seems like I need a hook form alter in a custom module but have not really done anything similar since D7.

Any help or guidance or resources is immensely appreciated!